# What does this line mean? LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES

Tags: android, android-ndk

Very simple question, hoping for a very simple answer.  I've been looking at a lot of people's android.mk files and have noticed this line.  I had no documentation on it within my NDK's docs (at least `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES"` came up with nothing).  This was the only documentation I've read on it...goes way over my head...

Part 2: Am I correct in my assumption that I will need this line to use a pre-built shared library with another module?  Thanks guys (and gals)

> ### III. Exporting headers for prebuilt libraries:
>
> The example above was called 'naive' because, in practice, the code in
>   foo-user.c is going to depend on specific declarations that are normally
>   found in a header file distributed with the prebuilt library (e.g. "foo.h").
>
> In other words, foo-user.c is going to have a line like:
>
> ## include < foo.h >
>
> And you need to provide the header and its include path to the compiler
>   when building the foo-user module.
>   A simple way to deal with that is to use exports in the prebuilt module
>   definition. For example, assuming that a file "foo.h" is located under
>   the 'include' directory relative to the prebuilt module, we can write:
>
> `include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
>
> LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
>
> include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)`
>
> The LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES definition here ensures that any module that
>   depends on the prebuilt one will have its LOCAL_C_INCLUDES automatically
>   prepended with the path to the prebuilt's include directory, and will thus
>   be able to find headers inside that.

URL: http://www.srombauts.fr/android-ndk-r5b/docs/PREBUILTS.html

Comment: Yes.  you are correct in your assumption.  Make sure your `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` points to the includes directory for the .so file. YOU'RE WELCOME, ME!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following explanation for the `LOCAL_EXPORT_*` variables in [ANDROID-MK.html](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) in the docs folder of the r6 NDK:

> LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS
>      Define this variable to record a set of C/C++ compiler flags that will
>      be added to the LOCAL_CFLAGS definition of any other module that uses
>      this one with LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES.
>
> For example, consider the module 'foo' with the following definition:
>
> ```
>    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>    LOCAL_MODULE := foo
>    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.c
>    LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
>    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> And another module, named 'bar' that depends on it as:
>
> ```
>    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>    LOCAL_MODULE := bar
>    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bar.c
>    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DBAR=2
>    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
>    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> Then, the flags '-DFOO=1 -DBAR=2' will be passed to the compiler when
>      building bar.c
>
> Exported flags are prepended to your module's LOCAL_CFLAGS so you can
>      easily override them. They are also transitive: if 'zoo' depends on
>      'bar' which depends on 'foo', then 'zoo' will also inherit all flags
>      exported by 'foo'.
>
> Finally, exported flags are *not* used when building the module that
>      exports them. In the above example, -DFOO=1 would not be passed to the
>      compiler when building foo/foo.c.
>
> LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS
>      Same as LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS, but for C++ flags only.
>
> LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES
>      Same as LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS, but for C include paths.
>      This can be useful if 'bar.c' wants to include headers
>      that are provided by module 'foo'.

Comment: What a shame it does not work as advertised. In my case, in the library I am importing, I have "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES" for its headers. But for the library I am building, I still have to specify the same headers previously specified in "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES" because they are not included... This modified build system absolutely sucks.

Comment: @jww Is this for building with the AOSP source tree? Then you need `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS` instead of `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`...