# Is it OK to use LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in static libraries in Android.mk?

Tags: build, android-ndk

My specific problem was that I needed to use Android 'cpufeatures' library (described in docs/CPU-FEATURES.html in the NDK) in a project that has one shared library (the JNI interface) and two static ones.

The shared library does not use the cpufeatures library directly, instead it is used inside one of the static libraries.

cpufeatures is an Android 'import module'. Usage of import modules is fairly straightforward, requiring only the following steps (from CPU-FEATURES.html of the r8e version of the NDK):

> List 'cpufeatures' in your list of static library dependencies, as in:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
> ```
>
> At the end of your Android.mk, import the 'android/cpufeatures' module, as in:
>
> ```
> $(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
> ```
>
> In your source code, include the header named

If I add cpufeatures to the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES of my main library, however, the include path for cpufeatures is available only when the main library is built, not when the static library is built, and thus compilation fails.

The contents of cpufeature's Android.mk and [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7247971/395370), together suggest that it should be OK to instead add a LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES to the shared library itself, like this:

```
...
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := CommonClasses
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(MY_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MY_COMMON_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(wildcard $(MY_COMMON_CLASSES_SRC_PATH)/*.cpp) \
...
$(wildcard $(MY_COMMON_CLASSES_SRC_PATH)/sound/*.cpp)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
...

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

And, indeed, that works, I can now include the library's header like this in source files compiled as part of the static library:

```
#include <cpu-features.h>
```

The reason I am asking, is that it makes little sense to link a static library with another static library. However, it seems that the semantics of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES is more abstract.

Is this the right way to do it, i.e. can I expect this to continue working and not cause me unexpected grievances later on?